# JSpec vs Jasmine vs QUnit for javascript and jQuery testing in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I am looking for a unit testing framework to use with javascript that integrates well with Rails 3.0

Anyone with experience with above frameworks can share their experience?

** UPDATE: JSpec is now discontinued as per their Github repository: http://github.com/visionmedia/jspec so this leaves Jasmine and QUnit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used QUnit on projects written in .NET and Java. In both worlds, we had to homebrew the integration. I don't expect Rails integration to be any more forthcoming.

Answer (score 7):

Jasmine works just fine with Rails 3, check out for how to integrate it: http://pivotallabs.com/users/dwfrank/blog/articles/1427-jasmine-in-rails-3

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [qunit for rails](http://github.com/mkrisher/qunit_for_rails) plugin if you use Qunit.